# Why does the following radio stream URL works in a browser but not in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

```
http://stream.rfi.fr/rfimusiquemonde/all/rfimusiquemonde-64k.mp3
```

I have all the plugins to play radio. Other radios play well. If I paste that link as is in Chromium it works. Rhythmbox just says (paused) and nothing happens.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to install 'ubuntu-restricted-extras' to make Rythmbox to play these internet radio stations

Here is the steps on how to install '**ubuntu-restricted-extras**'. Click on the below link

[ubuntu-restricted-extras](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-restricted-extras) [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras]

Or you can open up a terminal and run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras]

This is a bug in Ubuntu 13.04 and more information about bug can be found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1153934).

Also you can try out the Workaround suggested in lp:

> WORKAROUND: Run the command `sudo killall gvfsd-http` after playing a
>   station.

Comment: The killall command totally worked Oo'
How man a bug :(
Now I need to find a way to run that command any time I click on a radio x)